# Reloading only the body of page angular 2

Tags: jquery, angular, datatables, reload

I'm working on angular 2 app and I've defined a navbar component, mydata component and I created a small php script that return a json table to consomme it with mydata component and organize the data in a dataTable, everything work but the problem that when I start the server for the first time the JQuery dataTable plugin does not appeared only if I reload the navigator.

[image: before reloading the page]

[image: after reloading the page]

any one have an idea can explain the problem ?

Answer (score -1):

I think reloading the page is the only way to refresh the component after an asynchronous call in Angular. You could use window.location.reload after the AJAX call or can load the component after the AJAX call's response is obtained.